# How to show that $1/2^{100\log(n)}$ and $e^{-100\log(2) \log(n)}$ are equal?

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation

Suppose $A = 1/2^{100\log(n)}$, and $B = e^{-100\log(2) \log(n)}$.

I'm required to prove that $A$ and $B$ are equal, how should I prove this? I tried applying some rules of logarithms that I have learned but I'm not able to show this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**

take logarithm and use

$$\ln(A)=\ln(B) \implies A=B$$

and

$$\ln(\frac 12)=-\ln(2)$$

Comment: @Fatima Thank you so much for the hint!

Answer (score 2):

Got it now!

$e^{\log x}=x$, so $e^{\log A} = A$.

Consider now,
\begin{align*}
A &= e^{\log A}\\
&= e^{\log{(1/2^{100\log(n)})}}\\
&=e^{-\log{2^{100\log(n)}}} \quad &&\text{(division rule)}\\
&=e^{-100\log(2)\log(n)} \quad &&\text{(power rule)}\\
&=B.
\end{align*}

Thank you for the hints.